# How to read a parameter of a PLSQL stored procedure from Pentaho Spoon

Tags: oracle10g, pentaho-spoon

I'm quite new to Pentaho

I've created a Trasformation where I create a node "Execute SQL script" and where I insert into the SQL script box:

```
declare
  result   number;
begin
  -- Call the procedure
  prc_my_procedure(result);
end;
```

and I've signed the flag "Execute as a single statement"
I run the trasformation, it works, because I've cheked what it's been done in the Oracle database, but how can I read the content of the variable "result" returned by the procedure so as to use it in the next step of the trasformation?

I've also tried by defining a node "Call DB Procedure" but it doesn't work

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Mark

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use funtion output console DBMS_OUTPUT like this example:

```
declare
  result   number;
begin
  -- Call the procedure
  prc_my_procedure(result);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(result);
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

There might be another way of getting the result of a procedure stored in a parameter, but another idea would be to use a transformation with a **Table Input** step, and use this code as the query in the table input:

```
SELECT prc_my_procedure(result) AS my_value FROM DUAL
```

Afterwards, you can use a **Set Parameter** step to pass the result in *my_value* wherever you need it.